# Applying a dictionary to a string sentence

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, dictionary

Is there a fast way to apply a dictionary defined for a given number of letters to a string formatted word that contains more than one of them?

e.g.

```
def decode(code):
key = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
return key[code]


print decode("eddcab")
```

and get back from this

```
544312
```

I am aware it doesn't work this simply but is there like some trick or easy way to go around this or I need to define the operations separately from the indices [1:2] and then from [2:3] until I get to the end of the string?
I am using python 2.7

I appreciate any hints or advice related to this.

Comment: You can split the string to characters and `for` each character, you need to look in the dictionary, get the value and store it in a list. Then concatenate all elements of that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just rebuild the number using the dictionary values in a list comprehension, with 0 as default:

```
def decode(code):
    key = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
    return "".join([str(key.get(c,"0")) for c in code])

print(decode("eddcab"))
```

result:

```
544312
```

given the values you don't need the dictionary at all, just use offsetted character codes:

```
def decode(code):
    return "".join([str(ord(c)-ord('a')+1) for c in code])
```

Comment: You are right. I was mistaken with a common function to classes. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import maketrans

def decode(code):
    key = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
    keys, values = zip(*key.items())
    return code.translate(maketrans(''.join(keys), ''.join(map(str, values))))
```

If the dict's values can be strings, there's no need for `map(str, values)`.

---

If `values` can be strings, this can be further simplified:

```
def decode(code):
    key = {'a': '1', 'c': '3', 'b': '2', 'e': '5', 'd': '4'}

    return code.translate(
        maketrans(
            *map(''.join, zip(*key.items()))
            )
        )
```